# PHP Conditional Formatting with MySQL thresholds table

Tags: php, mysql

I want the text colors to change based on the target. Basically anything between 0 and 100 would be green and between 100 and 125 would be yellow and anything beyond 125 would be red. But that's only for 1 specific department. Let's say I have someone in another department that doesn't have the same threshold then anything below 150 would be green and etc...

This is the code I am using.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Department']."</td>";
    if (($row['Hold'] >= 0) && ($row['Handle_Time'] <= 100)) {
        echo "<td style=\"color:#005e20; font-weight: bold;\">".$row['Handle_Time']."</td>"; //green
    } elseif (($row['Handle_Time'] >= 100.01) && ($row['Handle_Time'] <= 124.99)) {
        echo "<td style=\"color:#e77904; font-weight: bold;\">".$row['Handle_Time']."</td>"; // yellow
    } elseif ($row['Handle_Time'] >= 125) {
        echo "<td style=\"color:#FF0000; font-weight: bold;\">".$row['Handle_Time']."</td>"; // red
    } else {
        echo "<td>".$row['Hold']."</td>"; // no color
    }
echo "</tr>";
}
```

What I have in mind is a MySQL table that has the threshold of each department. Each person has a department code and I want the department to match the target and change color accordingly.

Here's the target table called `stats_threshold`

```
 Department    Metric       Target  Yellow  Red
------------------------------------------------------
 WR            Handle_Time  100.00  124.99  125.00
 CA            Handle_Time  100.00  124.99  125.00
 RET           Handle_Time  120.00  169.99  170.00
 CET           Handle_Time  200.00  249.99  250.00
```

How do I query the department code to match the department in my table then `echo` the target and threshold. Expected result (The color column doesn't exist, it's only to show what the text color should be)

```
 Department   Handle_Time   Colors
------------------------------------------------------
 CA            66           GREEN
 CA            118          YELLOW
 CA            137          RED
 WR            96           GREEN
 WR            102          YELLOW
 WR            143          RED
 RET           119          GREEN
 RET           163          YELLOW
 RET           240          RED
 CET           199          GREEN
 CET           201          YELLOW
 CET           251          RED
```

Comment: You don't need the "Red" column in stats_threshold as it is always > "Yellow". But I don't get your exact question. You have everything you need. You just need to replace the fixed value inside your comparison in the first code snippet with the data from stats_threshold.

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear. I don't know how to set it based on the department code. I know I have to do a query but don't know how I should do it to match the department code of that line

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know how to set it based on the department code.

From what I'm seeing, you want to set the values in each column based on the value in `Handle_Time`. You're trying to define the standards that a given department should achieve, `Green` being the best, `Red` being the worst. While I'm not sure this is the way I would implement it, I would look at it like so:

**Step 1**

Obtain the data for the transaction. So let's assume you've done that, and you've got:

```
Department    Handle_Time
CA            118
```

**Step 2**

Grab the data from the table that contains the standards.

```
$department = $row['Department'];
// Make sure database request using the department. Something like:

$statement = $pdoOj.prepare("SELECT * FROM stats_threshold WHERE Department = :dep");
$statement.bindParam(':dep', $department);
// Remember to use prepared statements!

$statement->execute();
$targets_row = $statement->fetchAll();
```

**Step 3**

You're simply going to compare the value in handle time with the values in each of the columns. So:

```
$handle_time = $row['Handle_Time'];

if($handle_time <= $targets_row['Target'])
{
    // Output Green.
}
else if($handle_time <= $targets_row['Yellow'])
{
    // Output Yellow.
}
else
{
    // If it's not less than the target, and not less than yellow, it's red.
}
```

**Just a side note**

You're using the `mysql_*` library. I'm afraid this is now deprecated, so you should try to switch to either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you choose `PDO`, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/apis-php-pdo-mysql.html) Is a tutorial from the people at `MySQL` on it's use with their DBMS.